# i am trying to open whatsapp & send the particular mobile no with photo in flutter?

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

String url =
"whatsapp://send?phone='+91$number''text=$message'&photo=$imagePaths";

**My url is this how to send photo in flutter with a particular number**

Comment: the image is not passing

Comment: i want a link which i can try